# Keeping controls in the visible area

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a grid with several TextBoxes in it. I want to keep this grid fixed at the bottom of my main window. So if the user scrolls down the grid should basically stay in it's place.

One way I thought of doing this was to get some sort of value from the ScrollViewer and add it to the grids Canvas.TopProperty. However I am not sure which value changes when the user scrolls up or down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then don't put the scroll on the main window.  Put ScrollViewer only on the content (rows) that you want to scroll.  Careful not to use an auto for the height of the rows with the ScrollViewer or the container will grow to support all the content and the Scroll does not come into play.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <!--Hardcoded listbox items just to force the scrollbar for demonstration purposes -->
        <ListBoxItem>Item1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item5</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item6</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item7</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item8</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item9</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item10</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item11</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item12</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item14</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item15</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item16</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item17</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item18</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item19</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item20</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item21</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item22</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <Grid Panel.ZIndex="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="DarkGray">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">Text box 1</TextBox>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">Text box 2</TextBox>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">Text box 3</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```